# Problems with ColdFusion form submit

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I have the below form in my ColdFusion page:

```
<form name="adminsignin" action="swipelogin.cfm" method="POST">
    <input type="password" class="rounded" name="adminpin" id="adminpin">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In" name="adminpinbutton" id="adminpinbutton">
</form>
```

On click of the button, I submit the form using JQuery as below:

```
$("#adminpinbutton").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($.trim($('#adminpin').val()).length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'swipelogin.cfm',
                data: $('#adminsignin').serialize(),
                success: function(data, textStatus) {
                    $('#inputarea').replaceWith($('#inputarea', $(data)));
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, e) {
                    alert(status, e);
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("PIN missing or Incorrect.");
        }
    });
```

The problem is that in the `swipelogin.cfm` page, I am not able to access the form's input element.
I've tried `form.adminpin` and it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

**Edit: swipelogin.cfm code**

```
<cfoutput>#form.adminpin#</cfoutput>
<cfif (#isDefined("form.adminpin")#) OR (#isDefined("session.isadmin")# AND #session.isadmin# eq "true")>
```

This works perfectly fine if I use cfform instead of form.

**Edit 2:**
I just tried `$("#adminsignin").submit();` instead of a `$.ajax`. That gives me the form data in the ColdFusion page. This means the issue is with the Jquery.ajax() and not the ColdFusion page.

Comment: Can you post some of your code on swipelogin.cfm?

Comment: Writing "it doesn't work" doesn't work.

Comment: @PeterBoughton You can only get data or not get data from an input element, so when I say it doesn't work, I mean I don't get the entered value. I thought that was pretty obvious.
Also, I've specifically said "I am not able to access the form's input element"

Comment: Do a cfdump of the variables scope on the first line of swipelogin.cfm to see the available data.

Comment: Your code looks right.... try <cfdump var="#form#">

Comment: @DanBracuk I did a cfdump and I get an empty struct. I am suspecting that this could be because of the ajax submit I am doing.

Comment: What does `console.log($("[id=adminsignin]").length)` give you? both before binding the click event, and as the 2nd line of the click event handler.

Comment: @KevinB it gives me 0 and so does `alert($('#adminsignin').serialize());`. Does this mean the JQuery selector is not working?

Comment: That means your form doesn't have an `id="adminsignin"` (and it infact doesn't in the code posted above). You need to select the form by name, or give it the id.

Comment: @KevinB Yup! just figured it out. I just had a `name` and not `id`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector for selecting the form to get it's data is wrong, you need to either select the form by name

```
$("form[name=adminsignin]")
```

or give it the id you are targeting

```
<form id="adminsignin" ...>
```